# React-native scrollToRow by row id?

Tags: react-native

How to do a scroll to the certain row on ListView?

Comment: what react native version are you using? Are you using >= 0.43 by any chance?

Comment: This feature its a basic one. Please RN team include it!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a ref to your row inside your renderRow method. Then call this.refs.row.measure to get its x y coordinate. After your component is mounted, you can use this.listview.scrollTo method to scroll to that row. Hope this can help you.